# how to access object property using forEach loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm looping through object `sliced` where I want to extract properties `name` into `theRest` variable. With code below I get an error `Cannot read property name of undefined`

My object `sliced` gives me an array: `[{name: 'Bart'},{name: 'Lisa'},{name: 'Maggie'}]`

```
const theRest = sliced.map((item, i) => {
  item[i].name;
})
```

Sorry for variables naming if tht's confusing but I hope you get an idea.

Comment: well forEach returns undefined so not sure why you have `let theRest =`

Comment: What is the actual code....

Comment: So you want to use `map` instead of `forEach`? Also, it’s just `item`, not `item[i]`.

Comment: I think you should look at what forEach does...

Comment: This looks good as stands. I see you edited the question since map iterates over the array you don't need to use the index [i] you can just do `item.name` and don't forget to return the value from your function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you're getting an error is because when you're using [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), `item[i]` would be looking for an index in an object that isn't an array (`sliced` is an array, `item` is the currentValue in the array being processed). If you wanted to use your code, you should change `item[i].name` to `item.name` and it should work. I recommend that you use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead to get the results you're looking for.

```js
let arr = [{name: 'Bart'},{name: 'Lisa'},{name: 'Maggie'}];
let theRest = arr.map((item) => item.name);
console.log(...theRest);
```